# Swagger support in grails 2.4.x not working

Tags: grails, swagger

I am running Grails 2.4.3  and want to create Swagger-documentation for the REST endpoints. 
I have followed the documentation on https://rahulsom.github.io/swaggydoc/guide/installation.html.

In buildconfig.groovey I have added the following  :

```
    repositories {mavenRepo "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"}
    dependencies {compile "com.github.rahulsom:swaggydoc-commons:0.28.0"}
    plugins {compile "swaggydoc:0.28.0"}
```

In the projects plugins folder I can see swaggydoc-0.20.0 and the class ApiController

In config.groovy I have added:

```
swaggydoc {
    contact = "developer@coder.com"
    description = "API Description"
    title = "API Title"
    apiVersion = "1.0"
}

grails.mime.disable.accept.header.userAgents = []
```

I have updated one of the controller classes with the following:

```
  import com.github.rahulsom.swaggydoc.*
  import com.wordnik.swagger.annotations.*

   @Api( value = 'MeterController')
   class MeterController {
       MeterService meterService

       static responseFormats = ['json']

       def index() {
```

After starting my Grails-application via the grails run-app command and opening my application by entering http://localhost:8080/api  I get a 302 and see the following in the logs:

```
filter.UrlMappingsFilter Matched URI [/api] to URL mapping [/(*)/(*)?/(*)?], forwarding to [/grails/api.dispatch] with response [class org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade]
filter.UrlMappingsFilter Executing URL mapping filter...
```

which looks like it's falling in the following catch all in UrlMappings.groovy:

```
    "/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
     constraints {
            // apply constraints here
        }
    }
```

If I comment this out and run the call again I get a 404 and the following in the log:

```
filter.UrlMappingsFilter Executing URL mapping filter...
filter.UrlMappingsFilter No match found, processing remaining filter chain.
```

I have also tried the following in the urlmappings.groovy

```
    "/myapi" (controller: "api")
```

but still no joy.

Is there anything obvious that I am doing wrong?

Comment: I tried this plugin but would not get success. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44000065/swagger-grails-integration.  Did you find the solution?

Comment: I did get it to work -- the problem was shiro was blocking the /api endpoint. What error are you getting?

Comment: i posted the error at  stackoverflow.com/questions/44000065/swagger-grails-integrat‌​ion.