# Swagger grails Integration

Tags: rest, api, grails, groovy, swagger

I am new to swagger and I want to integrate swagger to Restful API project using grails framework. Please help if anybody have any idea what i am doing wrong?

my grails specification as below:

```
    | Grails Version: 3.0.7
    | Groovy Version: 2.4.4
    | JVM Version: 1.8.0_71
```

Did some settings for swagger as below:

in build.gradle:

```
    dependencies {
        ...
        compile "io.swagger:swagger-core:1.5.3"
        compile "io.swagger:swagger-jaxrs:1.5.3"
        ...
    }
```

in resources.groovy

```
    import io.swagger.jaxrs.config.BeanConfig
    beans = {
        swaggerConfig(BeanConfig) {
            def serverUrl = "http://localhost:8080/" 
            def hostName = "localhost:8080" 
            resourcePackage = "grails.rest.example" 
            host = hostName
            basePath = "/api"
            version = 'v0' // Default "1".
            title = 'Core Registration API, Version V0' 
            description = 'API for Accessing secured resources'
            contact = 'testtest@mailinator.com'
            license = ''
            licenseUrl = ''
        }

        corsFilter(CorsFilter)
    }
```

Added a Controller ApiDocController.groovy:

```
    package grails.rest.example.apidoc

    import grails.web.mapping.LinkGenerator

    class ApiDocController {
        LinkGenerator grailsLinkGenerator
        def apiDocService
        def index = {
            String basePath = grailsLinkGenerator.serverBaseURL
            render(view: 'index', model: [apiDocsPath: "${basePath}/api/swagger-json"])
            //render(view: 'index', model: [apiDocsPath: "localhost:8080/api/swagger-json"])
            //render(view: 'index', model: [apiDocsPath: "localhost:8080/dist/index.html"])

        }
        def swaggerJson = {
            render apiDocService.generateJSON()
        }
    }
```

Added a URLMapping for controller:

```
    "/api/info"(controller: 'ApiDoc')
    "/"(controller: 'Index')
    "500"(controller: 'InternalServerError')
    "404"(controller: 'NotFound')
```

Added a service ApiDocService.groovy:

```
    //package com.care.apidoc
    package grails.rest.example.apidoc

    import io.swagger.jaxrs.config.BeanConfig
    import grails.transaction.Transactional
    import io.swagger.util.Json

    @Transactional
    class ApiDocService {

        def swaggerConfig

        /*
         * generates SWAGGer JSON
         */
        def generateJSON() {

            String[] schemes = ["http"] as String[]
            swaggerConfig.setSchemes(schemes)
            swaggerConfig.setScan(true)
            def swagger = swaggerConfig.getSwagger()

            Json.mapper().writeValueAsString(swagger);
        }
    }
```

added Swagger-ui in src/main/webapp/dist folder

```
    with a working customised API URL "http://localhost:8080/api/orders" in index.html
```

added CorsFilter setting in src/main/groovy/CorsFilter.groovy

```
    import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter
    import javax.annotation.Priority
    import javax.servlet.FilterChain
    import javax.servlet.ServletException
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse

    @Priority(Integer.MIN_VALUE)
    public class CorsFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

        public CorsFilter() { }

        @Override
        protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

            String origin = req.getHeader("Origin");

            boolean options = "OPTIONS".equals(req.getMethod());
            resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, authorization, accept, content-type, x-requested-with");
            resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS");
            resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");

            resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin == null ? "*" : origin);
            resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");

            if (!options) chain.doFilter(req, resp);
        }
    }
```

On starting the server.
API for orders is working correctly, however, when I try to load the API in Swagger UI index file. it shows. 
        No operations defined in spec!

as attached in a pics. 
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is http://localhost:8080/api/orders the endpoint that delivers the Swagger spec? because from the looks of things, that is just the endpoint of a certain path... You need to load the Swagger spec JSON into swagger-ui. It won't auto-discover your API or anything.

Comment: What install guide did  you follow ?  you steps look a lot more complicated than the ones in https://rahulsom.github.io/swaggydoc/guide/installation.html

Comment: now i have updated the project with https://rahulsom.github.io/swaggydoc/guide/installation.html guide. it works fine. but need to add more annotations to controllers as compare to Springfox.

Comment: To use swagger with grails. Currently, we can use these two plugins based upon the grails version. rahulsom.github.io/swaggydoc/guide/installation.html or http://springfox.io/

Comment: Directly use the swagger wth grails creates many hindrance. Swagger team will launch the new version in near future.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [springfox](http://springfox.io)?

Here is a  [sample Grails Application](https://immense-escarpment-17128.herokuapp.com/swagger-ui.html) hosted in Heroku that demonstrates the capabilities of springfox integrating with it to produce the service description in the Open API specification 2.0 (fka swagger). The source code for the demo is [available here](https://github.com/springfox/springfox-grails-demo).

You can see this demo running live here demonstrating the Open API specification generated by the grails application and rendered using swagger-ui.

The library that makes this possible is [springfox-grails-integration library](https://github.com/springfox/springfox-grails-integration). It is about to be released and probably needs a little bit of work to make it a grails plugin. There is some [preliminary documentation](https://github.com/springfox/springfox-grails-integration) of how to configure this the library repository.

NOTE: This only works with grails 3.x

Also it was a notable library showcased in the [SHOW US YOUR GRAILS](https://objectcomputing.com/products/grails/show-us-your-grails/) contest. Feedback to improve this library is much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, I saw this. Thanks, Dilip, for your help. please tell me that is this Springfox compatible with grails 3.0.1?

Comment: Error while compiling SpringFox

  grails run-app --stacktrace
  | Error Error occurred running Grails CLI: No profile found for name [rest-api]. (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
  java.lang.IllegalStateException: No profile found for name [rest-api].
   at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.initializeProfile(GrailsCli.groovy:354)
   at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.execute(GrailsCli.groovy:196)
   at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.main(GrailsCli.groovy:99)

Comment: @AtifHussain the rest-api profile is only available post 3.1 however a any regular grails 3 application should be supported out of the box as well

Comment: Thankyou very much Dilip Krishnan

Comment: @DilipKrishnan does springfox work with OAS 3.0 ?
Do you plan to maintain springfox-grails integration ?

Comment: It doesn’t yet support it. Plan is to support it. Yes defenitely plan to support grails as well. Note that as of today grails 3.3 support seems to be broken.